# Php simplyfy code

Tags: php, simplify

How can I simplify this code to escape the need to reproduce the same code for the 3 distinct values!? For example, in the current code, I parse the 3 URL addresses to make sure they are directed to the right destination, so people don't set up various crazy URL addresses. But in the future, I might expand to more social media URLs and it would be tedious to repeat the code over and over. Thanks for your time!

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

$facebook = strtolower($_POST['facebook']);
$twitter = strtolower($_POST['twitter']);
$youtube = strtolower($_POST['youtube']);



$fb_exp = explode("facebook.com", $facebook);
$tw_exp = explode("twitter.com", $twitter);
$yt_exp = explode("youtube.com", $youtube);



if(($fb_exp[0] == 'http://' || $fb_exp[0] == 'http://www.' || $fb_exp[0] == 'https://' || $fb_exp[0] == 'https://www.' || $fb_exp[0] == '') && $facebook != ''){

    $facebook = 'https://www.facebook.com'.$fb_exp[1];

    $fb = 1;

}elseif($facebook == ''){

    $facebook = '';

    $fb = 1;

}else{

    echo 'Not a Valid Facebook Page !';

}



if(($tw_exp[0] == 'http://' || $tw_exp[0] == 'http://www.' || $tw_exp[0] == 'https://' || $tw_exp[0] == 'https://www.' || $tw_exp[0] == '') && $twitter != ''){

    $twitter = 'https://www.twitter.com'.$tw_exp[1];

    $tw = 1;

}elseif($twitter == ''){

    $twitter = '';

    $tw = 1;

}else{

    echo 'Not a Valid Twutter Page !';

}



if(($yt_exp[0] == 'http://' || $yt_exp[0] == 'http://www.' || $yt_exp[0] == 'https://' || $yt_exp[0] == 'https://www.' || $yt_exp[0] == '') && $youtube != ''){

    $youtube = 'https://www.youtube.com'.$yt_exp[1];

    $yt = 1;

}elseif($youtube == ''){

    $youtube = '';

    $yt = 1;

}else{

    echo 'Not a Valid YouTube Page !';

}



if($fb == 1 && $tw == 1 && $yt == 1){

    $text= '<?php $title="'.$_POST['title'].'";
            $subtitle="'.$_POST['subtitle'].'";
            $email="'.$_POST['email'].'";
            $tel="'.$_POST['tel'].'";
            $add="'.$_POST['add'].'";
            $facebook="'.$facebook.'";
            $twitter="'.$twitter.'";
            $youtube="'.$youtube.'";
            ';
    $fp = fopen('text.ini','w');
    fwrite($fp,$text);
    fclose($fp);
    header('Location: http://somesite.com/index.php');

}
```

}

Comment: Try creating a function then pass the url addresses as the parameters. So whenever you need to parse the url addresses, you just have to call the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use loop, for example `foreach`:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
  $valid = true;
  $links = [];
  $list = ['facebook' => 'facebook.com', 'twitter' => 'twitter.com', 'youtube' => 'youtube.com'];
  foreach($list as $key => $domain) {
    if(isset($_POST[$key])) {
      $exp = explode($domain, strtolower($link));
      if($link != '' && ($exp[0] == 'http://' || $exp[0] == 'http://www.' || $exp[0] == 'https://' || $exp[0] == 'https://www.' || $exp[0] == '')){
          $links[$key] = 'https://www.'.$domain.$exp[1];
      }elseif($link == ''){
          $links[$key] = '';
      }else{
        echo 'Not a Valid '.ucfirst($key).' Page !';
        $valid = false;
      }
    }
  }

  if($valid) {   
    $text = '<?php $title="'.$_POST['title'].'";
            $subtitle="'.$_POST['subtitle'].'";
            $email="'.$_POST['email'].'";
            $tel="'.$_POST['tel'].'";
            $add="'.$_POST['add'].'";
            $facebook="'.$links['facebook'].'";
            $twitter="'.$links['twitter'].'";
            $youtube="'.$links['youtube'].'";
            ';
    $fp = fopen('text.ini','w');
    fwrite($fp,$text);
    fclose($fp);
    header('Location: http://somesite.com/index.php');
  }
}
```

Regular expression instead of many conditions:

```
foreach($list as $key => $domain) {
  if(isset($_POST[$key]) && preg_match('#^(?:https?://(?:www\.)?)?('.$domain.'.*)$#i', strtolower($_POST[$key]), $matches)) {
    $links[$key] = 'https://www.' . $matches[1];
  } else {
    echo 'Not a Valid '.ucfirst($key).' Page !';
    $valid = false;
  }
}
```

Comment: Best solution :) you forgot to define $link as in $link = $_POST[$key]; The regular condition hurts my eyes tho, but is a good choice as well :D

Comment: Also, strtolower becomes obsolete as the URLs have to match with the ones in the list, and in the case of youtube, the link strains are case sensitive! So removing it solves both situations.

Answer (score 1):

You could simplify with `parse_url` and using loops to handle arrays:

```
$smPass = 0; 
$correctUrls = array('facebook'=>'https://www.facebook.com','twitter'=>'https://www.twitter.com','youtube'=>'https://www.youtube.com');
$output = array('facebook'=>'','twitter'=>'','youtube'=>'');
foreach($_POST as $social=>$value){

    if(in_array( $social, array_keys($correctUrls) )) {

        if(empty($value)){
            $smPass += 1;
        }
        else {

            if($urlParts = parse_url($value)) {

                if( in_array($urlParts['host'], array_keys($correctUrls)) ) {
                    $output[$social] = $correctUrls[$social].$urlParts['path'].'?'.$urlParts['query'];
                    $smPass += 1;
                }
                else {
                    echo 'Invalid '.$social;
                }
            }
            else {
                echo 'Invalid '.$social;
            }
        }

    }

}
if($smPass == 3){

    $text= '<?php $title="'.$_POST['title'].'";
            $subtitle="'.$_POST['subtitle'].'";
            $email="'.$_POST['email'].'";
            $tel="'.$_POST['tel'].'";
            $add="'.$_POST['add'].'";
            $facebook="'.$output['facebook'].'";
            $twitter="'.$output['twitter'].'";
            $youtube="'.$output['youtube'].'";
            ';
    $fp = fopen('text.ini','w');
    fwrite($fp,$text);
    fclose($fp);
    header('Location: http://somesite.com/index.php');

}
```

Comment: Elegant choice ^_^